# Adding paygate buttons to HTTP-only website?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

Let's say that I have a website where I want to sell homemade goods. I want customers to be able to pay for the goods without too much hassle.

A common option is to use buttons provided by a payment service like PayPal. The website uses HTTP, however, and the hosting service does not allow SSL certificates without paying for a higher hosting plan. What are the risks of using similar payment methods on my website?

One attack I am aware of, is that of an attacker redirecting the traffic to their own website — which pretends to be the payment service. I am not sure if this is even a concern for this case.

To be clear:

- Purchases on the website will be rare, so there will be little opportunity for an attacker to intercept payments.
- The website is hosted by a hosting service, similar to WordPress.

Comment: If I was using the site and saw the HTTP warning message, I certainly would not be using it to buy anything. There's a higher-order risk to consider.

Comment: Change hosting providers to something that allows the now ubiquitous TLS and Let's Encrypt?

Comment: Why not transfer the whole purchase process to a separate eStore where you don't have to worry about these risks?

Comment: I'm helping someone else who wants to do this. I would rather just add a link to another e-commerce site like Etsy. I would like to know what the risks are, though.

Comment: I think the risks are just the bog standard risks that TLS mitigates: the content is secured from view and modification, you mitigate mitm redirecting and spoofing. If the connection to the payment processor is secured, there should be no risks to the customer.

Comment: @schroeder true, but the link to the payment processor itself could be modified

Comment: If the hosting provider does not offer HTTPS without extra cost, they obviously are not up to date with regards to security best practices. Who knows what other problems they have. Move to a different hosting provider.